# Property typed lodash compose function

Tags: typescript, lodash.js

Here I created a typed version of [lodash  `flow`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#flow) that offers more specific typing.

I'm curious if this exists in any other library, which optimized in tying any way — offering mainly it up to the world as a better version of `flow`.

1. The return value is set to the return in the last passed function
2. The input value is set to the input of the first given function
3. In between functions are checking the return types from the proceeding function match the inputs of the next.

Here's the code:

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

namespace Compose {
    export type ReadFuncs = readonly ((x: any) => any)[]
    export type Tail<T extends ReadFuncs> = ((...a: T) => void) extends ((h: any, ...r: infer R) => void) ? R : never;
    export type Func = (...any) => any
    export type Funcs = Func[]
    export type LengthOfTuple<T extends any[]> = T extends { length: infer L } ? L : never;
    export type LastInTuple<T extends ReadFuncs> = T[LengthOfTuple<Tail<T>>];
    export type LastFnReturns<Fns extends ReadFuncs> = ReturnType<LastInTuple<Fns>>
    export type FirstFnParam<Fns extends ReadFuncs> = Parameters<Fns[0]>
    export type CheckFns<T extends readonly ((x: any) => any)[]> = { [K in keyof T]:
        K extends keyof Tail<T> ? (
            [T[K], Tail<T>[K]] extends [(x: infer A) => infer R, (x: infer S) => any] ? (
                [R] extends [S] ? T[K] : (x: A) => S
            ) : never
        ) : T[K]
    }
}

function compose<T extends Compose.ReadFuncs, R extends Compose.LastFnReturns<T>>(...t: Compose.CheckFns<T>) {
    return (...input: Compose.FirstFnParam<T>) => {
        return _.flow(t)(...input) as R
    }
}

const x = compose(
    (foo: string) => `wrapFoo1(${foo})`,
    (foo: string) => `wrapFoo2(${foo})`,
    (foo: string) => `wrapFoo3(${foo})`,
    (foo: string) => `wrapFoo4(${foo})`,
    (value: string): number => value.length,
)

const velvet = x('meow')

console.log(velvet)
```